# Angularjs - Retrieve html of page given a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I get html-code of a webpage from an angular directive? 
in my example I have an html code:

```
<div class="modal-body" data-ng-bind-html="myHTML">
</div>
```

I want to place inside the div the content of another page! In my directive I do something like:

```
$rootScope.myHTML = link;
```

Where link should contains the whole html of the page! If myHtml="http://www.google.com", how can I retrieve the content of 'link'?

Comment: Have you looked at how to use an `<iframe>`?

Comment: $http.get will help you... but you will need to define the return type... originally it will expect a json (I believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you really just want to apply the external site inside your view, and then you should just link it in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly insert all the html of directive in html it self only. In your parent html you can insert directive.html like

```html
<directive></directive>
```